# Transform nested list into object - Javascript

Tags: javascript, list, object, task, generate

we need help to resolve this problem, no one in our enterprise was able to do it.

We have a String like this:

```
- name
    - type
        - string
    - validation
        - required
        - minLength
            - 4
        - maxLength
            - 20
        - optionIn
            - option1
            - option2
            - option3
            - option4
- password
    - type
        - string
    - validation
        - required
        - minLength
            - 6
        - maxLength
            - 30
- date
    - type
        - date
```

And we need to generate an object like this:

```
{
   name: {
      type: 'string',
      validation: {
        required: true,
        minLength: 4,
        maxLength: 20,
        optionIn: ['option1', 'option2', 'option3', 'option4']
      }
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      validation: {
        required: true,
        minLength: 6,
        maxLength: 30
      }
    },
    date: {
      type: 'date'
    }
}
```

A few things that make this really a complex task:

If the last nested item is just one, that makes him the value of the previous key. If the final nested item are more than one, they become an array, and the array is the value of the previous key.

Edit:
Thanks @adiga for the insight, into the example 'required' becomes a object with value true, because his mates have a nested item

Is its a hard and complex task, libraries are available to use if you need to.

Comment: Format your code correctly please. The string specifically. And rephrase your question, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Jabberwocky what do u dont understand of the question?

Comment: Why is `required` a boolean and has a `true` value but `option1`, `option2` are array items? How do you distinguish between them?

Comment: @adiga Because required didn't have any child but the other values have, that make it an object

Comment: If that tree structure looking string is literally all the starting information you have, it will be impossible to create something from it, because it does not have enough information to know which items are keys and which are values.

Comment: You need to be a lot more clear on your desired output. What is the "final nested item" ?  How can an "item" singular be more than one? Give an example of your nested list and the desired output.

Comment: So if `optionIn` array has only one item, it becomes a string property according to your strcuture

Comment: @adiga exactly.

Comment: @Herohtar fixed, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I've come up with is a two step process.

First I `parse()` the `inputStr` into an intermediate form in the simplest way I can which ends up looking like this:

```
{
    "name": {
        "type": {
            "string": null
        },
        "validation": {
            "required": null,
            "minLength": {
                "4": null
            },
            "maxLength": {
                "20": null
            },
            "optionIn": {
                "option1": null,
                "option2": null,
                "option3": null,
                "option4": null
            }
        }
    },
    "password": {
        "type": {
            "string": null
        },
        "validation": {
            "required": null,
            "minLength": {
                "6": null
            },
            "maxLength": {
                "30": null
            }
        }
    },
    "date": {
        "type": {
            "date": null
        }
    }
}
```

Then I `transform()` that intermediate object into the final form.

```js
const inputStr = 
`- name
    - type
        - string
    - validation
        - required
        - minLength
            - 4
        - maxLength
            - 20
        - optionIn
            - option1
            - option2
            - option3
            - option4
- password
    - type
        - string
    - validation
        - required
        - minLength
            - 6
        - maxLength
            - 30
- date
    - type
        - date`

let parseLimit = 1000;
function parse(lines, curIndent = 0) {
 if (parseLimit-- < 0) throw "parseLimit exhausted";
 if (lines.length === 0) return null;
 
 const obj = {};
 let parent = null;
 let descendantLines = [];
 [...lines, '>'.repeat(curIndent)].forEach(line => {
  const indents = (line.match(/>/g) || []).length;
  if (indents === curIndent) {
   if (parent) {
    obj[parent] = parse(descendantLines, curIndent + 1);
   }
   descendantLines = [];
   parent = line.replace(/>/g, '');
  } else if (indents > curIndent) {
   descendantLines.push(line);
  } else {
   throw 'indents < curIndent';
  }
 });
 
 
 return obj;
}

let transformLimit = 1000;
function transform(node) {
 if (transformLimit-- < 0) throw "transformLimit exhausted";
 
 const childKeys = Object.keys(node);
 const leafChildKeys = childKeys.filter(childKey => {
  return node[childKey] === null;
 });
 if (childKeys.length === leafChildKeys.length) {
  //all leaf children
  const values = childKeys.map(value => {
   return isNaN(value)
    ? value
    : +value;
  });
  return values.length === 1
   ? values[0]
   : values;
 } else { //not all leaf children 
  const newNode = {};
  
  childKeys.forEach(childKey => {
   if (leafChildKeys.includes(childKey)) {
    //true
    newNode[childKey] = true;
   } else {
    //recurs
    newNode[childKey] = transform(node[childKey]);
   }
  });
  
  return newNode;
 }
}

function solve(str) {
 const lines = str
  .split('\n')
  .map(line => line
   .replace(/    /g, '>')
   .replace('- ', '')
  );
 return transform(parse(lines));
}

console.log('input:\n', inputStr);
console.log('solution: ', solve(inputStr));
```

Comment: Oh men, you are awesome!. Thanks, i will show your answer to the team.

Comment: Happy to help : )

Comment: We made littles chages to your snipper (like change spaces for tabs) and works beautifull. Really clever answer. Thanks again Rocky, YOU ROCK!!

Comment: You've probably just built an entire feature for the OP. Marvelous work.